# How can we describe a group of things as having just the right number, i.e., not too many, not too few?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I'd like to use a single word or an idiomatic expression to express that the school's breaks are well-spaced and *not too many*. Is there an adjective that mean just the appropriate number?

Comment: I'm sure someone can think of one, but I can't at the moment. Any of the ways you've already described it would be fine.

Comment: A good starting point for answering these questions is to begin with the word in your language, and use a bilingual dictionary to give suggestions of possible words.  If no such word exists in your language then you might be lucky, there might be a word in English, but probably not. Would a phrase like "ideal number of" work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ***optimum/optimal***

> best; most likely to bring success or advantage; best; the best or most effective possible in a particular situation ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/optimum))

As in this [medical article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11539389/):

> Is there an ***optimum*** number of night shifts?

You could say that the school's breaks have *optimal frequency* or *distribution*.

Answer (score 0):

Many options:

> There are the ...
>
> - perfect
> - ideal
> - appropriate
> - right
> - correct
> - optimal
>
> ... number of breaks

You need to describe the *number* not the breaks. So I don't think that there is an expression *The breaks are* .